# How do you test for an exception in python 3 with pytest when the exceptions are chained

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have some code that uses custom exceptions in python 3.

something like:

```
def get_my_custom_error():
    try:
        1.0/0.0
    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        raise MyCustomError() from err
```

and in my test file I have the following:

```
with pytest.raises(MyCustomError):
    get_my_custom_error()
```

I currently get an output like

```
ZeroDivisionError
    
the above exception was the direct cause of the following error:

MyCustomError
```

This causes the test to fail.

So the code appears to be working, but pytest doesn't seem to be checking the highest level error (which is what I would like it to do).

Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0
pytest 3.0.7

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: If I place this code in a simple test file and run it with pytest (3.4.0), it works for me. Are you sure this is the source of your problem? Since it sounds like you've tried to provide a generic example, is it possible for you to instead provide the specific code and test that's failing? Along with a stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

Catch and check it explicitly:

```
try:
    get_my_custom_error()
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    assert hasattr(err, '__cause__') and isinstance(err.__cause__, MyCustomError)
```

Comment: I have a similar scenario but the `__cause__` is `None`, so this doesn't work. Curious if it works for anyone else.

Comment: I don't have a different case, mine is identical. For whatever reason, `pytest` only 'sees' the inner exception, whether I use your catch here or `pytest.raises`. But there's obvsly something weird going on b/c everything I'm reading says it should see the outer error. I'm on an old Python, I'll test a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Building off phd's answer, you can use `pytest.raises` to catch the top-level `MyCustomError` exception, then inspect the object returned by `pytest.raises.__enter__` to verify that the chained exception is an instance of `ZeroDivisionError`.

```py
with pytest.raises(MyCustomError) as exc_info:
    get_my_custom_error()

err = exc_info.value
assert hasattr(err, '__cause__')
assert isinstance(err.__cause__, ZeroDivisionError)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works at least on python=3.10, pytest=7.4:

```py
with pytest.raises(ZeroDevisionError):
    with pytest.raises(MyCustomError):
        get_my_custom_error()
```

Notice that the order matters. It must follow the order how the exception is raised.